# Calculate area of the region formed by $f(x)= x^3-x^2$ and x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the area of the region formed by the graph of $f(x)=x^3-x^2$ and the $x$-axis in the interval $[0,3]$?

Did I do this right?

I get $$\int_0^3x^3-x^2\,dx$$ giving me the answer of $45/4 = 11.25u^2$ ?

Comment: Hi, please read this and try to use it!
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that sometimes the graph of $x^3-x^2=x^2(x-1)$ is below the $x$-axis on the interval $[0,3]$.  When it is below the $x$-axis the integral will count that area as negative.  So, you need to split the integral into pieces.  On subintervals where the graph is above the $x$-axis, you integrate $x^3-x^2$.  When it is below the $x$-axis, you integrate $-(x^3-x^2)=x^2-x^3$.

Comment: I'm still confused could u break it down in steps please on how to solve this problem